# Jquery UI Plugin for Flow Charts in React JS

Tags: jquery, reactjs, jquery-ui, dom, jquery-plugins

I have been using react for a few months, and getting very used to it, but have been struggling to find a way to integrate classical js libraries in to it. I understand that you would create a component that wraps the functionality, but I haven't found succinct instructions on doing so.
I want to include this [Jquery UI plugin](http://sebastien.drouyer.com/jquery.flowchart-demo/) as its a nice flow chart library.

Could anyone help me get a component that loads the example in so that I can use it elsewhere in my app?
I've tried loading the scripts directly in my html file, and importing jquery within the component and even importing the js/css files directly into the component, but Im not in a bit of a code mess, lost as to what does what and how and why I can't connect dom elements to the jquery library. Confusion is an understatement!

Instead of "giving a man a fish" I'd be happy if someone had generic instructions for loading jquery plugins into react, or perhaps seeing how to do this one would help me going forward.

Thanks

Comment: Some advice, you don't need jQuery, and it doesn't play nice with react so just leave it out and find a react solution.

Comment: yeah i read that, i haven't found a react flow chart library quite as nice as this one. I realise its hacking the old and the new though